# Telnet Email Automation

Tags: bash, automation, smtp, telnet

I am writing a bash script so that I can send an authenticated email over telnet. I am running into problems since telnet opens a prompt when a connection is established and my following commands are not executing since I am stuck in the telnet prompt.

Is there a way to execute multiple telnet commands in one line? The commands I would like to send in one line are as follows:

```
telnet 1.2.3.4 25
HELO 1.2.3.4
AUTH LOGIN
djwijdoawd
igjifidjei
MAIL FROM: user1@lab.com
RCPT TO: user2@lab.com
DATA
Hello world!
quit
```

I am looking for something like this (but it does not work):

```
telnet 1.2.3.4 25 && HELO 1.2.3.4 && AUTH LOGIN && djwijdoawd && igjifidjei && MAIL FROM: user1@lab.com && RCPT TO: user2@lab.com && DATA && This is a test! && quit
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're stuck is because shell scripts don't treat the lines after `telnet` as input to the command, they're more commands to be run locally when `telnet` finishes.

Use a here-document to turn them into input.

```
telnet 1.2.3.4 25 <<'EOF'
HELO 1.2.3.4
AUTH LOGIN
djwijdoawd
igjifidjei
MAIL FROM: user1@lab.com
RCPT TO: user2@lab.com
DATA
Hello world!
quit
EOF
```